# Drupal image resize into second imagefield

Tags: drupal, resize, field, image-resizing, imagefield

can a drupal cck imagefield be automatically resized into a second cck imagefield?

maybe using imagecache? but i need the resized image to be in it's own unique cck field with unique fid so I can use it with file_download in views. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to have two files created when you upload one, each stored in a different CCK field under Drupal 6 ? Do I understand correctly ?

I think you could use http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6 in the 'presave' action of hook_nodeapi.